# How to add Active Directory module in PowerShell in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, powershell, active-directory

I use Windows 8.1 and I try use `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`, but I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module : No se cargó el módulo 'ActiveDirectory' especificado porque no se encontró ningún archivo de módulo
válido en ningún directorio de módulo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Import-Module ActiveDirectory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (ActiveDirectory:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

How to add Active Directory module in PowerShell? What can I install to get Active Directory module ?

Maybe useful could be do all steps programmatically (perhaps using chocolatey or another)

Comment: Did you install the RSAT for Windows 8.1 tools? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39296

Answer (score 4):

STEP 1.) Download and install **Remote Server Administration Tools** (RSAT) for Windows 8.1 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39296

STEP 2.) For x64, install **Windows8.1-KB2693643-x64.msu**

STEP 3.) Active Feature

Select **AD DS and AD LDS Tools** and then select *Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell*.

To turn off specific tolos

1.On the desktop, hover in the upper right corner of the screen, and then click Settings.
2.On the Desktop menu, click **Control Panel**.
3.Click Programs, and then in Programs and Features, click Turn Windows features on or off.
4.In the Windows Features dialog box, expand **Remote Server Administration Tools,** and then expand either **Role Administration Tools or Feature Administration Tools**.
5.Clear the check boxes for any tools that you want to turn off. Click OK, and then close Control Panel.

STEP 4.) Open a PowerShell prompt and type `PS C:\> Get-Module –ListAvailable`.

STEP 5.) To ensure the Active Directory Module is present, using PowerShell type `PS C:> Import-Module ActiveDirectory`.

NOTE: You will need to do this for every PowerShell session.

If you wish to have the Active Directory Module automatically loaded any time you run PowerShell, prepare a shortcut with the following content: `%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command import-module ActiveDirectory`

STEP 6.) `PS C:> Get-ADGroupMember "MY CUSTOM GROUP IN AD" | select name`

Appenders:

Installation and Uninstallation of MSU in silent mode 
http://msiworld.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/silent-install-and-uninstall-of-msu.html

Sources: 
https://support.software.dell.com/es-es/appassure/kb/117489
https://kiquenet.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/installing-powershell-active-directory-module-for-windows-8-1/

Comment: The module will automatically load when needed if it is installed. This has been the case with PowerShell 3.0 and up.